# Sharepoint 2010 :Add webpart page and insert custom webpart in it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, web-part-pages

I have many site collections, where I want to add a webpart page named "reporting.aspx" and insert a developped webpart (c#) in it, 
How can I create this feature and activate it automatically ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can add page with your web part is using **Module**.
I am sharing some links here like [SharePoint-deploy-webpart-page-using-module](https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/sharepoint-deploy-webpart-page-using-module/) and [Quick-tip-provisioning-web-parts-to-a-page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2011/04/04/quick-tip-provisioning-web-parts-to-a-page/) which shows you how to Create page using module. 
Add this module in one feature and activate it in all site collection where you want this page.

Comment: thanks @SID , I found this link, but I have a custom webpart so where should I search for my webpart name to  call it ? in this line  <metaData>
                <type name="WebpartPages.MyWebpart.MyWebpart, WebpartPages, 
                Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=132122a1200767d5" />
                <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
              </metaData>

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. You can find your <metaData> of webpart information from .webpart file of your webpart from visual studio..